# How to draw the following graph from the given definition

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_{1i} = G_1 $ and $G_{2i} = G _2 (1 \le i \le k)$ be $k$ copies of graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Let $G_3$ be an arbitrary graph.

The first operation $G_1\sim _k (G_3 \times G _2 )$ of $G_1$ , $G_2$ and $G_3$ is obtained by making the Cartesian product of
two graphs $G_ 3$ and $G_ 2$ , thus produces $k$ copies $G_{ 2i}; (1 \le i \le k)$ of $G_ 2$ , then makes $k$ joins $G _{1i} \vee G _{2i} $ where $i = 1,2,...,k.$

I dont understand the above definition and how the graph $G_1\sim _k (G_3 \times G _2 )$ is done for arbitrary graphs.

Can someone kindly explain the above graph for $K_2\sim _k (C_4 \times P_3 )$
where $K_2$ is complete graph on $2$ vertices ,$C_4$ is the cycle on $4 $ vertices and $P_3$ is path on $3$ vertices.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your explanation. Can you give a reference to the definition?

Comment: @saulspatz;https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0972860017301706

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't follow it.  It doesn't seem like $_3$ enters into the definition in any meaningful way.

Comment: @saulspatz;so do you mean that the definition given in the linked paper is wrong?

Comment: It seems like there's a mistake in the statement, but since I don't know what the definition should be, I can't say.  It starts out saying you take the Cartesian product of $G_2$ and $G_3$ and then that doesn't seems to get used anywhere.  I just don't know what to make of it.